# GraphQL MongoDB: Implementing cursor-based $text $search pagination

Tags: mongodb, pagination, graphql, database-cursor

In a normal cursor pagination, I would filter and sort the documents based on `created` field, which is pretty simple. like this:

```js
// `cursor` is a string
const books = await this.BooksModel.find({
    ...(cursor ? { created: { $lt: new Date(cursor) } } : null),
})
    .sort({ created: -1 })
    .limit(first)
```

Meanwhile when implementing search, I (think I) have to sort and filter the documents based on `textScore` metadata, which could have a duplicates. To prevent this I need another field to filter, which is `_id`. I imagine it would be something like this:

```js
// `cursor` is { id: string, score: number }
const books = await this.BooksModel.aggregate(
    [
        { $match: { _id: { $ne: ObjectId(cursor.id) }, $text: { $search: 'sed' } } },
        { $project: { title: 1, score: { $meta: 'textScore' } } },
        { $match: { score: { $lt: cursor.score } } }
    ]
)
```

To achieve the example above, I need the cursor to contain not only the document `_id` (like a normal pagination) but also the `score`. I imagine the length of the cursor (decoded) would be very long compared to the normal one. Moreover, the cursor now contains an object instead of just string, which is pretty weird to a noob like me. Is this really the way to build cursor-based search pagination?

Comment: I'm currently running into this dilemma. The problem with this solution is that the results are not sorted by `ObjectId`. If three results have the same `score` and someone uses the cursor from the second result then the first and third will be returned (even though the first was already included in the previous page) or neither the first nor the third will be returned (never showing the third to the user). Maybe something like matching results with less than a score OR the same score and an `ObjectId` less than the cursor's `ObjectId`?

Comment: With respect to the composition of the cursor I believe it is ok to have both `score` and `ObjectId` within it. If you are concerned with the size of the cursor you could concatenate them into `<score>:<ObjectId>` instead of stringifyed JSON.